# CacheManager handles with inproc and Redis as backplane is not synced

Tags: c#, cachemanager

I have this this scenario using CacheManager (https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager):

- 1 console application (with inproc cache handle + Redis cache handle as backplane)
- 1 ASP.NET MVC web application (with inproc cache handle + Redis cache handle as backplane)

The cache configuration for both console application and ASP.NET MVC application are the same:

```
var configuration = ConfigurationBuilder.BuildConfiguration(settings =>
        {
            settings                    
                .WithSystemRuntimeCacheHandle("InProc")
                .And
                .WithRedisConfiguration("redis", config =>
                {
                    config.WithAllowAdmin()
                        .WithDatabase(0)
                        .WithEndpoint("localhost", 6379);
                })
                .WithMaxRetries(1000)
                .WithRetryTimeout(100)
                .WithRedisBackplane("redis")
                .WithRedisCacheHandle("redis", true);
        });

        ICacheManager<string> cache = (ICacheManager<string>)CacheFactory.FromConfiguration(typeof(string), configuration);
```

However when I do a simple cache invalidation from console application like this:

`cache.Remove("Key")`

It's not removed from inproc cache handle on web application. I have experimented and created 2 different console applications with the same configuration as above and this works just like expected (when one of the console applications invalidate a key from the cache it's also removed from all cache handles on the other console application).

Is it something special going on using CacheManager when used with web application and console application which means that the cache synchronization is not working?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so after some more research into this I realized the console application uses version 1.1.2 of CacheManager and the web application uses version 1.1.1. After an upgrade this suddenly started working.

So the answer to anyone else experiencing this problem is to make sure that you are using the same version of this library on all processes accessing the cache. However, unless if this is a bug that was resolved in 1.1.2, I feel that this should work even with different versions. After all it's pubsub from the redis backplane that keeps this in-sync...